# loading multiple files of different lengths into one large array in openmp

Tags: arrays, fortran, openmp

I have 4 files (file1,file2,file3,file4) of different lengths (n1,n2,n3,n4) which each contain the following type of data:

```
x1,y1,z1
x2,y2,z2
...
xn,yn,zn
```

What is the quickest way to load these into memory - can it be done simultaneously to create one large array (i.e. totarray(1:n1+n2+n3+n4,1:3)) from the 4 smaller arrays? If this can't be done in openmp - what would be the fastest way to do this? At the moment, I simply loop over each filename and added it to the bottom of a temporary array which is filled with the new data in each iteration. There are millions of entries in each file and I want to speed this read in up. Thanks

Comment: Could you show exactly the lines which read in the data? If you're just reading 1 line at a time that can almost certainly be improved, while parallelism depends on the hardware you are using - if you only have 1 disk head parallelism ain't going to get you very far.

Comment: I am reading in the entire data at once i.e. read(1) pos where pos is an allocated Nx3 real*8 array. It looks like I can't do it.

Comment: What you could consider instead is using asynchronous I/O, if your compiler supports it. You can then overlap the reading and processing of data, synchronising afterwards with a `wait` statement. Another way of speeding up data transfer is to provide the data in binary format.

Comment: Are the files made from within the program, or a separate program?

Comment: The files are already made and are just sitting in a directory.

Comment: Why not concatenate them using `cat` in the terminal? It'd be something like `cat file1 file2 file3 file4 > allfiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless each file is on a different medium, the fastest way of doing this is probably to read the files one at a time, which is what is sounds like you're doing. In this case, OpenMP will not help you, and might make things worse, as the threads would be competing for a single, slow disk. This assumes that you are I/O bound, though.

You do not specify what format your file is in, though. If it is in binary format, then you can't do much better unless you want to start with compression. If it is in text format, though, you are probably CPU bound due to all the text parsing involved, and can probably get huge speedups simply by moving to a binary format. This will be much more efficient than OpenMP parallelization would be.

[HDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) is a good binary format you might consider, but you could also go with something as simple as fortran "unformatted" files.